# How to set the max value at 5 in a radar graph in Excel whereas all the values are smaller than 4

Tags: excel

I have an excel radar graph.

I have many criteria. Every criteria has to have a value between 0 and 5. But if all the values are strictly smaller than 4, then the graph considers 4 as the max value, but I still want 5 to be the max value.

How to do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say what version of excel you are using but you can change axis min and max in a radar chart just like any other chart.

select the chart
on format tab select Radar Axis from the drop down (under current selection tab)
Click format selection and then change your min and max.

Answer (score 4):

You can click on the chart and go to the ‘+’ beside the chart which shows the chart elements. The first element is ‘Axes’.
If you hover the arrow more right on the ‘Axes’ row, you will see a small black arrow that you click -> then click ‘More Options’ and you can change the Minimum and Maximum bounds of it .

Answer (score 1):

Coincidently enough had the same issue with the same max value.

First right click for "Select Data..." On the left side for Legend Entries. Click on "Add" and you will come to an "Edit Series" popup. Give it a "Series name" and for the "Series values" input "={5}" instead of the default "={1}". And that's it. You should have two Legend Entries; one for your main data source i.e. Series1 and the new one just created.